# Solution of $(DA+AD)^T=B$ about D?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-decomposition

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{D}_{t} & \triangleq \underset{\mathbf{D} \in \mathcal{C}}{\arg \min } \frac{1}{t} \sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{1}{2}\left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{D} \boldsymbol{\alpha}_{i}\right\|_{2}^{2}+\lambda\left\|\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{i}\right\|_{1}, \\
&=\underset{\mathbf{D} \in \mathcal{C}}{\arg \min } \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{D}^{T} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{A}_{t}\right)-\operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{D}^{T} \mathbf{B}_{t}\right)\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
where $x_i$ denotes the data vector, $\alpha_i$ denotes the corresponding sparse coefficient. $\mathcal{C}$ denotes the domain of solutions $D$.
$$\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{A}_{t} \leftarrow \mathbf{A}_{t-1}+\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{t} \boldsymbol{\alpha}_{t}^{T} \\
\mathbf{B}_{t} \leftarrow \mathbf{B}_{t-1}+\mathbf{x}_{t} \boldsymbol{\alpha}_{t}^{T}
\end{array}.$$

For solving the problem above, I tried to calculate its partial derivative with respect to D as $\frac{\partial L}{\partial D}=(DA+AD)^T-B=0$.

So what should I do to obtain the optimal $D$ by iteratively using this equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For better understanding of your question, please consider it typing! And please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Tanks, more details have been added.

Comment: Explain your symbols. Is $\mathbf x_i$ a column vector? What is $\mathcal C$?

Comment: Hint: See [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). For the numerical solution, the article mentions the [Bartels-Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartels%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm)

Comment: more details are added. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Sylvester equation seems like the right solution to this problem! Thanks!